# Maven installation Error JAVA_HOME not defined correctly but it really is defined correctly

Tags: maven

Operating System Windows 10
`java version "1.8.0_161" - jre`

`C:\Users\admin>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\;`

```
Error (Command line)
C:\Users\admin>mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Comment: Did you google what the error means and how it can be removed. It's pretty simple though

Comment: I am getting the same error. My environment path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\
Even i have tried removing "\" but still the same error. The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the trailing backslash and especially the trailing semi-colon:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
```

By the way, you can display the current setting with the shorthand of typing "set" at a command prompt followed by the minimal number of characters needed, i.e. on my system:

```
set j
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, removing trailing backslash and semi colon solves the problem

Comment: Trailing slash was my issue. I thought it was a problem with windows path in git bash, but it was just the slash, thanks Bill.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Please remove the backslash('') and semicolon.

For windows 10, here are the steps:

1. Open Environment Variables
2. Select '`JAVA_HOME`' under system variables
3. Click Edit
4. Remove the `\;` from path under the 'variable name'.
5. Click 'OK'

Done.
RUN the `mvn -version` command and it shall work.